# How to handle unwanted pets in a "light side" manner?

Tags: star-wars-kotor

Landing on Tatooine, I ended up with a bunch of Gizka on my ship. I already saw Gizka poison at a trader, so I *could* get rid of them. But then again, I'm a light side jedi (at least [for now](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28894/which-gender-suits-which-side-of-the-force-better)), so what's the most "good" procedure to deal with them? Do they pose a threat at some point or can I just let them hop around?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not gain any Dark side points for dealing with the Gizka infestation with poison.

However there is an alternate way to handle it,  on Manaan there is a person who can take them off of your hands. But if you don't take either of those actions near the end of the game they will just leave.

Comment: so there's no harm in doing nothing either?

Comment: Just annoyance at seeing your ship infested with cute creatures.

Comment: @Arkvie well, I'll try to live with _that_ fate

Comment: There **is** however, an XP reward for, erm... Dealing with them.

Comment: Are the XP rewards different for the two methods of dealing with them, @LessPop_MoreFizz?